# update array value of a specific key

Tags: php, arrays, session

I've got an array containing animals. I print out the array using a foreach loop. I would like to update the value of a specific key, without changing any of the other values which have different keys. I have an update input box next to each key for the value to go in it. When I type a value for key 0, for example, all the other key values change too, not just 0

So my output is something like this:

```
The value of $_SESSION['0'] is 'cat'          // i want to change cat to something else
The value of $_SESSION['1'] is 'dog'          // dog to something else
The value of $_SESSION['2'] is 'mouse'        /mouse to something else
```

this is my code and it so frustrating becuase I have added $key to each input in the foreach loop...

```
**code 
    <?php
// begin the session
session_start();

// create an array
$my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird', 'crocodile', 'wombat', 'koala', 'kangaroo');

// put the array in a session variable
$_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;





// loop through the session array with foreach
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

 // and print out the values
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';


// getting the updated value from input box
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $aaa = $_POST['aaa'];


// setting the session spesific session array value different for each key  
 $_SESSION['animals'][$key] = $aaa;
}
    ?>
<form method="post" action="testthis.php">

<input type="text" name="aaa" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" size="2" />
<input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="submit"/></div>

</form>
    <?php

}
echo"<br/>---------------------------------------------------------<br/>";
//echoing out the results again for the updated version
foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{ 

// and print out the values
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';

}

?>
```

Comment: You need to give each of your `<form>`s in your loops a unique attribute, ie. `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" />`. Then inside your `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {...}` you would only set to that posted `id` value, ie. `if($_POST['id'] == $key) { $_SESSION['animals'][$_POST['id']] = $aaa; }`

Comment: Oh wow! i cant believe it I didnt think of that. I will try it right now. I really hope it works!! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Can i ask, why is the input type hidden? because the input box needs to be visible to be able to updated with the value for the key

Comment: The lines 
`foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
{   

 // and print out the values
echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';` 
are not printing `$_SESSION[$key]`, they're printing `$_SESSION['animals'][$key]`, which might be misleading you a bit.

Comment: It is hidden so that they key is not changed in addition to the value. You would only change the value, not the key, as if you changed the key you might as well just add a new key=>value.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code.

Edits:

1) move `isset($_POST["submit"])` outside `foreach` loop so that it will not update all the sessions.

2) take hidden input with the value of key to be updated so that we can concentrate only on one key which is to be updated.

```
 <?php
    // begin the session
    session_start();

    // create an array
    $my_array=array('cat', 'dog', 'mouse', 'bird', 'crocodile', 'wombat', 'koala', 'kangaroo');

    // put the array in a session variable
    if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))
        $_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;

    // move submit code outside of foreach loop
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
    {
        $aaa = $_POST['aaa'];
        $key_var = $_POST['ke'];

        // setting the session spesific session array value different for each key  
        $_SESSION['animals'][$key_var] = $aaa;
    }



    // loop through the session array with foreach
    foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
    {   

        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';

        // getting the updated value from input box
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" name="aaa" value="<?php echo $value ; ?>" size="2" />
            <!-- take a hidden input with value of key -->
            <input type="hidden" name="ke" value="<?php echo $key; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="submit"/></div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }

    echo"<br/>---------------------------------------------------------<br/>";
    //echoing out the results again for the updated version
    foreach($_SESSION['animals'] as $key=>$value)
    { 
        // and print out the values
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes it works, the values are updated to each individual key. Thanks Suyog and everyone for their input!!!

Comment: I will definitely! just one question, if i move the submit button out of the foreach loop, to the bottom of the code. will i be able to update it all at once? becuase each one is updating but when when updating another one, the value goes back to the non updated value

Comment: this is because you have initialized `$my_array` in the beginning of the page so every time the page refreshes, the array is initialized to the very initial values

Comment: see the updated code now. I have added `if(!isset($_SESSION['animals']))` this before assigning values to `$_SESSION['animals']`. It will first check if values are assigned to `$_SESSION['animals']` or not and it will assign values only if it is not assigned any value previously...!!